How to ensure subprocess sees mock patched variable?
I have unit tests that look like the following:
with patch('my_module.file_in_module.SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE', new=mocked_var):
    subprocess.check_call([
      # CLI omitted
    ])

If I print my_module.file_in_module.SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE right before the subprocess call it prints as mocked_var. However, when I step into the actual functionality that's being executed by the subprocess, and print SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE from file_in_module, it prints as the non-mocked variable. I think this makes sense since the mock only applies to the main thread and not to the subprocess. How can I mock the variable the subprocess sees in this case?

You have to get a better grasp of how Python handle variable names:
If in the module your actual calling code is you do something like
from mymdule.myfile import MY_VARIABLE, MY_VARIABLE is an independent name in that target module, and patching the original  MY_VARIABLE in my_module.myfile won't change it.
You eithre have to mock/patch MY_VARIABLE in the target module, or, modify the target module so that it retrieves MY_VARIABLE as my_module.my_file.MY_VARIABLE (or at least my_file.MY_VARIABLE): that way your code making use of  MY_VARIABLE will "see" the modified value.
The preferred approach is the later one, as it makes other changes, possibly even in running code rather than testing, take effect: always do:
from my_module import my_file # and use as my_file.MY_VARIABLE instead of from my_module.my_file import MY_VARIABLE: which implies that for any runtime change of MY_VARIABLE you will have to replace it in several places.

from mymdule.myfile import MY_VARIABLE is not in my code. MY_VARIBLE is defined in myfile only and only used in that file. I was able to use with patch('my_module.file_in_module.SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE', new=mocked_var): with success when I ran the a function in file_in_module that used the variable directly as opposed to the subprocess, so that's why I concluded the subprocess is the issue here

If you where using "subprocessing" or "concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor": those run the same Python code from the current program in the subprocesses, and the contents would be unpatched there. But subprocess is for arbitrary executables, and all the values passed to it should be picked from the current process.

Anyway, if that is not the problem, them we need more context to be able to answer your question: add the actual subprocess call, and the actual Python code making use of the patched variable, along with the imports in each file, and the functions called in the target module by the test.
